# How to parse a price with parseInt() correctly in JS

Tags: javascript, parsing, parseint

I'm trying to parse a price out of a html document and I'm encountering a few problems:

There are lots of divs above, hence I can't use parseInt() as usual. Here is how the class element looks like:

```
<div>
<span id="market_buynow_dialog_totals_total"  class="market_dialog_totals_cost">0,11€</span>
<span class="market_dialog_totals_label">Total:</span>
</div>
```

Furthermore there is a `,` and I don't want to be restricted to either the left or the right side of the `,`, in the example above I would love to get the int 11, for 399,99 I would love to get 39999.

Can anyone help me and show me how to achieve that? I'm not good enough to do this on my own, I tried for quite some time now. TY!

Comment: It is not clear if `,` is used for **Decimal Separator** or for **Digit Grouping**. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve an integer from the "market_buynow_dialog_totals_total" element you can use the following code.

```
function retrieveValue(id){
    return parseFloat(document.getElementById(id).innerHTML.replace(/[,€]/g, ""));
}
```

Comment: wouldn't this parse `10,50€` as `1050`?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `parseFloat`, replacing the comma with a period, and treat the number as a single decimal value.

The snippet below uses that approach (first result), and also uses `parseInt` to individually parse the groups of digits before and after the comma (second & third results) and all together as you suggested above (fourth result).

```js
var src = document.getElementById("market_buynow_dialog_totals_total");
var segments = src.innerText.split(",");
document.getElementById("result1").innerText = parseFloat(src.innerText.replace(/,/, "."));
document.getElementById("result2").innerText = parseInt(segments[0]);
document.getElementById("result3").innerText = parseInt(segments[1]);
document.getElementById("result4").innerText = parseInt(src.innerText.replace(/,/, ""));
```

```html
<div>
<span id="market_buynow_dialog_totals_total"  class="market_dialog_totals_cost">399,99€</span>
<span class="market_dialog_totals_label">Total:</span>
</div>
Parsed result as a decimal: <span id="result1"></span><br/>
Parsed result as an integer, left side: <span id="result2"></span><br/>
Parsed result as an integer, right side: <span id="result3"></span><br/>
Parsed result as an integer, both sides: <span id="result4"></span><br/>
```